# Python Code runs when I start Anaconda Navigator but not in env

Tags: python-pptx

Newbie Anaconda Python question. I installed `python-pptx` from conda, followed the pptx documentation. I install it to my env which has the dependencies pptx wants i.e

```
 Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.3, 3.4, or 3.6

 lxml

 Pillow

 XlsxWriter (to use charting features)
```

Then I change my kernel in Jupyter to 'my_env_name', I get this error in my env:

```
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pptx'
```

But when I run it in my (base) through Anaconda Navigator (i.e. change my kernel to 'Python3'  everything works fine.

Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

do you have more than one Python interpreter installed?

Edit: Solution here [How to add to the PYTHONPATH in Windows, so it finds my modules/packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-so-it-finds-my-modules-packages)

Comment: how do I check to see if I have more than one Python interpreter installed?   I have one anaconda installation and several ENVs.  For each ENV I have a ipykernel kernel installed

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: Windows 10 Enterprise

Comment: anecdotally if you have downloaded python.exe another time besides when you downloaded anaconda the answer is yes.
Try typing "python" into a windows cmd prompt

Comment: In CMD i get **H:\>python
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**
but in Anaconda Prompt I get **(base) C:\>python
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 17:13:21) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.**

Comment: it looks like you have not added python to your PATH. That can be found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-so-it-finds-my-modules-packages

Comment: The issue is i'm not admin on my system so path adding I cannot do.  Any workrounds in this case? Or this is the only way?

Comment: i do not know of any other way to get around this issue.